# how can i deploy Azure functions into AKS using Keda Scaledobjects

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

i have multiple trigger types like Eventhub,servicebus, Timer, Http,Eventgrid, so i want to  use scaled objects using KEDA.how can i write the yaml file for the scaledobjects.
i tried to write the trigger type one by one in same scaledobject.but its not showing when i check the Scaledobjects,only first Trigger type is getting displayed,

plz tell me  how to write

this is how i tried :

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: XXX-XXX-function-scaledobject
  namespace: backend-services
  labels:
    app: XXX-XXX-function
    deploymentName: XXX-XXX-function
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: XXX-XXX-function
  triggers:
  - type: azure-eventhub
    metadata:
      bootstrapServers: event-hub.servicebus.windows.net:9093
      lagThreshold: "50" 
  - type: cron
    metadata:
      schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 10 
  - type: HTTP
  - type: azure-servicebus
```

after this i am gettingerror like AZureWEBjob storage connecting string not found. tell me how to get the solution for this also.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error that you are seeing, you are likely just missing an environment variable for [`AzureWebJobsStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage) which is [required when using the Timer Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#azure-arc-enabled-clusters).

Also, not sure if it's just incorrect here in the post, but the HTTP and Service Bus triggers should be before the `minReplicaCount` and `maxReplicaCount` properties.